# Feedparser gives SAXParseException on 'valid' RSS

Tags: python, django, rss, django-templates, feedparser

I am trying to display content from an external rss feed on my django based site using a handy inclusion tag I found in this snippet: djangosnippets.org/snippets/311/

However, feedparser is choking on the rss feed in question (http://softplc.com/blog/blogs/xmlsrv/rss2.php?blog=2) which works just fine-and-dandy in an online rss viewer (www.seekfreak.com/rss/) as well as being declared 'valid' by [feedvalidator.org](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoftplc.com%2Fblog%2Fblogs%2Fxmlsrv%2Frss2.php%3Fblog%3D2)

Error received is: **SAXParseException('Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 7 and head\n',)**

...which would make sense, except there isn't a meta tag in the XML from that feed. It looks like feedparser is trying to read the html from softplc.com/blog/blogs/ instead of the full rss link or something? (and even then I don't see a tag mismatch as referenced)

So, what gives, feedparser?

Comment: Trying the same thing directly works -- `len(feedparser.parse('http://softplc.com/blog/blogs/xmlsrv/rss2.php?blog=2'))` gives 9, and no errors. Do you have the wrong URL or any kind of HTTP proxy?

Comment: Triple-checked URL. No proxy. There's a "len" on the stuff returned by parse, but it is a big pile of garbage from what I can see. At the end of the pile of goo is a little bit about the bozo_exception. Can't access anything like ['entries'] off of the return value, and `len(feed['entries'])` is 0 (obviously).

Comment: `len(f['entries']) == 10`, using [FeedParser](https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) 5.1.3.

Comment: Ok, did that in a separate environment, and got what you are getting. Is there some kind of result cache I can clear?

Odd that I'd see the same ?cached? result running under Django (pdb breakpoint in the inclusion tag code) as well as running feedparser direct in a python console. (but then see a different result on another box where it wasn't first run under Django)

Comment: To clarify: https://dpaste.de/CLdaf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little checking with wget, and whaddya know but I was trying to get the content from the wrong server. Long story short, there was an **/etc/hosts** entry mapping the domain in question to the external IP of the 'not working' box - delete that and all is well.

Excuse: box in question is being worked on as a replacement for the existing site, so it will eventually really BE the correct domain (just not yet).

@Joe - thanks for the sanity check, seeing that it was working elsewhere led to the fix!

***Word to the (un)wise: check your network stuff!***

Feedparser, I'm sorry I doubted you!